# how to compare each row in two tables with same name but in different dbs i.e oracle and sql server using soap UI PRO.

Tags: groovy, soapui

how to compare each row in two tables with same name but in different dbs i.e oracle and sql server using soap UI PRO. pls help

source is oracle and my destination is sql server , i have same table in both the dbs which resides in different machines. ineed to compare the data on both the tables ,using soap ui pro and groovy(  soap ui pro installed) in another seperate machine

Comment: Are you just testing databases? May be dbunit good option? Otherway using any soap / rest services and checking the result of these services in database ? i mean like add a record in soap test request /rest step and check db?

Comment: does this work if i have only acess to the db tables ,? does they need url of the applications ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SoapUI-Pro, you do not even need Groovy. You can do all this with just standard SoapUI steps.

First you will need to set up your [JDBC connections](http://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/jdbc-connections.html).

Next set up a [JDBC Data Source](http://www.soapui.org/data-driven-tests/functional-tests.html) step, reading from your reference database. Inside the Data Source loop, you will want to [read from your compare database](http://www.soapui.org/jdbc/testing-jdbc-databases.html), and make your checks. Note that internally, SoapUI converts everything to XML, and so you can use [XPath assertions](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) to make your checks.

Comment: thanks .. :) ..  is there any way to add a teststep datasource using groovy script. i have many tables that share same teststeps so i would like to add datasource test step to all the tables at one shot using groovy

Comment: i went well and added it sucessfully .  now im stuckup with adding a Properties teststep programatically using groovy and need to add some property names and its values

Comment: ive tried reading db for source and destination , and did looping for both  individually. but how can i compare the data on both are same ? can i do it using the same xpath assertions